Invalid ID being shown err_code 16 - Pardot API with Python Requests
I am running into an issue:
pardot_request = r.get(
    url= f"https://pi.pardot.com/api/email/version/4/do/stats/id/{account_engagement_id}?format=json",
    headers = {
        'Pardot-Business-Unit-Id': pardot_business_unit_id, 
        'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}",
        }
)
json.loads(pardot_request.text)

This leads to error which says:
{'@attributes': {'stat': 'fail', 'version': 1, 'err_code': 16},
 'err': 'Invalid ID'}

Question 1: In the API it says to use Account Engagement ID - is it the same as Prospect ID? Where can I find the true Account Engagement ID?
The code below works:
pardot_request = r.get(
        url= f"https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/read/email/{email}?format=json",
        headers = {
            'Pardot-Business-Unit-Id': pardot_business_unit_id, 
            'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}",
            }
    )
    # Convert JSON string to JSON object
    json_object = json.loads(pardot_request.text)

This provides me plenty of information about the email I pass including an id. This is where I pick the id:
"@attributes": {
        "stat": "ok",
        "version": 1
    },
    "prospect": {
        "id": 23117XXXX,
        "campaign_id": 14XXX,
        "salutation": null,
        "first_name": "Jonathan",
        "last_name": "Appleseed",
        "email": "jappleseed@company.com",
        "password": null,
...

Reference I am using: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/emails-v4.html#email-read
